# How to make my footer 3 column?

Tags: html, css

I have a site that i want to change little. Right now it doesn't look good. I really want to have 3 column footer. My footer is like this.

```
<div class="fl_r">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo main_url(demo_URL)?>"><?php echo lang('Member <span class="fg_demi">Area</span>')?></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo main_url(demo2_URL . '/register')?>" id="become_member"><?php echo lang('Members <span class="fg_demi">wanted</span>')?></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo main_url(demo3_URL)?>"><?php echo lang('Member2 <span class="fg_demi">Area</span>')?></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo main_url(demo4_URL)?>"><?php echo lang('Affiliates <span class="fg_demi">Area</span>')?></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="links">
        <a href="<?php echo main_url('documents/2257')?>"><?php echo lang('18 U.S.C 2257')?></a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="<?php echo main_url('documents/policy')?>"><?php echo lang('Privacy policy')?></a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="<?php echo main_url('documents/tos')?>"><?php echo lang('Terms & conditions')?></a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="<?php echo main_url('contact')?>"><?php echo lang('Contact us')?></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS look like this for my footer.

```css
#footer{
 width: 986px;
 margin:-65px auto 0px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 height:85px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius:  10px 10px 0px 0px;
    border-radius:  10px 10px 0px 0px;
 background: #3c3c3c; /* Old browsers */
 /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
 background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #3c3c3c 0%, #151515 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#3c3c3c), color-stop(100%,#151515)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #3c3c3c 0%,#151515 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #3c3c3c 0%,#151515 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #3c3c3c 0%,#151515 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(top,  #3c3c3c 0%,#151515 100%); /* W3C */
 -pie-background: linear-gradient(top, #3c3c3c 0%, #151515 100%);
 color: #fff;
 z-index:11;
    behavior: url(/style/css/pie/PIE.htc);

}

#footer .bl {
    background-position: -4px -219px;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 14px;
    left: -19px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 19px;
}

#footer .br{
 background-position: -23px -219px;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 14px;
    right: -19px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 19px
}

#footer a{
 color: #ffffff;
}

#footer .logo{
 font-size:30px;
 padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
}

#footer .copyright{
 font-size:11px;
 color: #666;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-align: center;
    width:300px;
    padding:0px 10px;
}

#footer .fl_r{
 text-align: right;
}

#footer ul{
 display:inlin-block;
 list-style: none;
}
#footer ul li{
 color: #CCCCCC;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0 10px;
 text-transform: capitalize;
}

#footer ul li a{
 color: #CCCCCC;
}

#footer ul li a .fg_demi{
 font-size:16px;
}

#footer ul li a:hover,
#footer .links a:hover{
 color: #ff1d23;
}

#footer .links a{
 color: #666666;
 text-transform: capitalize;
}

#footer .links{
 margin-right: 10px;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 11px;
 color: #666666;
}
#footer #langs{
 margin:3px;
}
```

Any one can help me to make my footer have some more unique look. Im not so good at this so i hope for some examples here. Please show your examples how i can do this simple and good. Thanks!

Comment: Any one please can tell me how to make this to 3 column?

Comment: Your code doesn't have anything!

Comment: Alter your question to add the content!!! What's there you have given?

Comment: Give us a link or just create a Demo [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the fiddle below please!!!

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

footer .col3 {
  width: 32%;
  background-color: #ccf;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="col3">Left</div>
  <div class="col3">Center</div>
  <div class="col3">Right</div>
</footer>
```